# How about Windows Softwares

Tags: 14.04, windows, crossplatform

If I have Windows 7 Pro in a partition and Ubuntu 14.04 in a other partition, I can emulate the windows in my partition using Ubuntu? and if not, when windows software become available for Ubuntu? (Platform switching)??? TY all also if my question has no answers!

Answer (score 4):

> If I have Windows 7 Pro in a partition and Ubuntu 14.04 in a other partition, I can emulate the windows in my partition using Ubuntu?

No.

> When windows software become available for Ubuntu?

Never.

Well never... the creator of the software needs to take Linux into account for it to be usable for us. Apache, MySQL, Chrome, Firefox are examples of those.

Comment: Apart from the many applications that have Linux versions as well :)

Comment: well technically those are then not Windows software ;)

Comment: Ah, you got me again :)

Comment: You could try with a "java is platform independent" @JacobVlijm :-D